# How to find which element inside visual tree is creating some visual part of control

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Lets say I have a complex user control (like GridView), and I extracted style from the Blend software. Now, since GridView is a complex control that contains subparts, how do I know which xaml element is responsible for some visual presentation? Just as example, how would I find witch element is drawing the border around the selected cell?

Is there some software that can help in inspecting the whole visual structure, and how is each part painted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view visual tree & different properties using next free software:

[snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/), [wpfinspector](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/)